# Ideal font and buttons sizes for a 32" monitor?

Tags: website-design, web-app, large-screen

Font size viewable from 5-7 feet away from a 32" Touchscreen, and button sizes ideal for a 32" touchscreen?

Answer (score 1):

The only UX answer is to not design in a vacuum.  Design it the best way you can - then look at the product in context; the same way the customer / user will.  There is no substitute for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the designs on your PC (and using the mockup sizes you intend to replicate), best believe that if it is 'viewable' on your PC, it will be viewable 5-7feet away.

Same goes for the 32' touchscreen, if it looks good on the prototype, it'll definitely look good in reality.

Comment: Do you _really_ mean `32'` (32 foot, such as [this inflatable one](https://www.amazon.com/Viewing-Projection-Inflatable-Screen-Patches/dp/B014I79XWG) or [this 34-foot one for cinemas](https://www.engadget.com/2017/07/14/samsung-made-a-giant-34-foot-led-tv-for-movie-theaters/)?